# How to solve "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1d in tid 18101" error in android?

Tags: java, android, segmentation-fault

This error occurs in my splash screen. I tried many things clearing cache and deleting .gradle file and all. My app uses the **SharedPreferences** for tracking some activities. Here is my splash Activity code. I tried with disabling Android hardware acceleration in manifest, But it stops all the animations and graphic things which is not a good way to solve.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LoginModel userInfo = null;
private int fieldId;
private LiveData<LoginModel> loginModelLiveData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    //transparent status bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    );
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.RyosharedPref), MODE_PRIVATE);
    String number = prefs.getString("phone", null);
    fieldId = prefs.getInt("fieldId", 0);

    RyoGasRepository ryoGasRepository = new RyoGasRepository(getApplication());
    loginModelLiveData = ryoGasRepository.getUser(number);
    loginModelLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(LoginModel loginModel) {
            if (loginModel != null) {
                userInfo = loginModel;
            }
            startAnimations();
            loginModelLiveData.removeObserver(this);
        }
    });
}

private void startAnimations() {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l = findViewById(R.id.splash_linear);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.ryo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    // Splash screen pause time
    // do nothing
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 2500) {
                    sleep(50);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                if (userInfo == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginSignUpActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                } else {
                    if (fieldId != 0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, GasPumpListActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
                    }
                }
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

}

Comment: SIGSEGV is indicative of something funky going on with a native instruction set memory store or load being addressed to an invalid pointer. Your program is pure Java, so you're not dealing with pointers. Hence something that your code is interfacing with is internally triggering a native level bug. Maybe have a look at the system log and look for a backtrace of the segfault there.

Comment: Okay i will let you know if i get any solutions over your suggestions.